# Passing html element to oncomplete function of a4j:jsFunction

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I need to pass the calling html element of a `<a4j:jsFunction>` to its `oncomplete` function. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359815/how-to-access-a-parameter-in-a4jjsfunctions-oncomplete-attribute) answer but I don't think passing the html element (as a string, I suppose?) to the bean and back is very elegant, and I think it's a bit messy.

Here's my **code**

```
<td class="col-md-2 clickable text-right"
        onclick="orderBy('getAmount','DESC')">
    #{msg.label_amount}
</td>

<a4j:jsFunction name="orderBy" action="#{backingBeanRef['orderBy']}"
        oncomplete="afterOrderBy()" 
        render="list_form" >
    <a4j:param name="ref" assignTo="#{backingBeanRef['orderByMethodName']}"/>                               
    <a4j:param name="ref2" assignTo="#{backingBeanRef['orderBySortOrder']}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

**Question**

Is there a way to pass an html element to the `a4j:jsFunction`, and have that one pass it to its `oncomplete` callback function, without sending the html element to the bean and back?

The **ideal solution** would be to add a param to the invoking side like `orderBy(... , this)` and the corresponding param to the jsFunction like `<a4j:param name="element"/>` :

```
<td class="col-md-2 clickable text-right"
        onclick="orderBy('getAmount','DESC',this)">
    #{msg.label_amount}
</td>

<a4j:jsFunction name="orderBy" action="#{backingBeanRef['orderBy']}"
                    oncomplete="afterOrderBy(element)" 
                    render="list_form" >
    <a4j:param name="ref" assignTo="#{backingBeanRef['orderByMethodName']}"/>                               
    <a4j:param name="ref2" assignTo="#{backingBeanRef['orderBySortOrder']}"/>
    <a4j:param name="element"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

But it doesn't work. I have a breakpoint in the first line of the js function and it doesn't get called.

I just added the `..,this)` to the *amount* column (the only one I'm showing), so if I click on the other columns (which don't have the `..,this)`) my js function does get called, only the parameter comes undefined.

So, is it possible to do this?

**Edit**

If I try to not add any `<a4j:param>`, and do `oncomplete="afterOrderBy(this)"` as pointed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780263/pass-source-html-element-to-oncomplete-function-of-primefaces-pajax) the element sent to the js function is a span (when I debug/log it to console, it has no `.source` child, and is

`...
outerHTML: "<span id=\"sgfrmId:j_idt601\" style=\"display: none;\"></span>"
...`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896283/calling-another-a4jjsfunction-in-an-a4jjsfunction-oncomplete-event) also points out some ways to do something similar but not this exactly.

**Edit2**

Just read in the docs that

> [...] It is not recommended to use use keyword this inside the
>   EL-expression, because it will not always point to the component where
>   Ajax request was initiated.[...]

So doing the `oncomplete="afterOrderBy(this)"` was wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The a4j:jsFunction only serves to trigger an ajax request, the oncomplete is executed as part of the server response (i.e. not within context of the function), simply save the element reference to a global variable and have the oncomplete code use that variable.

E.g.

```
<td onclick="sourceElement=this; orderBy();">…</td>

afterOrderBy = function() {
     // do something with sourceElement …
}
```

Comment: Oh of course! I get it. Thanks! It works as desired.

Comment: I'm curious cause I don't like to use global variables: would this be totally fine? Or would you approach it in a different way than I did?

Comment: Doesn't have to be global, point is the oncomplete method cannot reference the jsFunction parameters.

Comment: Yes I get that. I was asking if another approach would be best in this case. Since your answer is correct, I'll mark it as such and ask another question about this new approach thing. Thanks again.